# Is there a way to read top-level struct type using method defined in embedded struct?

Tags: go, reflection

To satisfy some interface, I need to add a method to every object, kind of like adding trait in object oriented languages.

The plan is to create *base struct* with such method and to embed it into other structs, which are sometimes embedded to another structs and so on.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type BaseStruct struct {
}

func (this BaseStruct) InterfaceMethod() {
    str := reflect.TypeOf(this).String()
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s", str))
}

type StructA struct {
    BaseStruct
}

func main() {
    baseStruct := BaseStruct{}
    structA := StructA{}

    baseStruct.InterfaceMethod()
    structA.InterfaceMethod()

}
```

Current output:

```
main.BaseStruct
main.BaseStruct
```

Desired output:

```
main.BaseStruct
main.StructA
```

Is there any way to check if struct is embedded in other struct, traverse through them up the top and read top-level struct name?

Go playground link:
https://play.golang.org/p/794lneEtByS

Comment: This is not possible in Go. If you need to know about who embeds a value, you must maintain that value yourself (e.g. the embedded value must have a parent field).

Comment: Ok, then I'll have to go with some other solution.
Thank you for super-fast response and linking to similar question